# Question on compactness of generator of unitary group

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, functional-calculus

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be complex Hilbert space. Suppose we have a unitary group $\{U_t\},t\in\mathbb{R}$ and by Stone's Theorem we have a unique infinitesimal generator $A:\mathcal{D}(A)\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$, which is a self-adjoint operator:
$$U_t = e^{itA} \quad t\in\mathbb{R}.$$
So, I wonder is this operator $A$ compact or not?
The reason why I ask this is that in P.Walter's Spectral Theorem for Unitary Operators he said "there exists a unique finite Borel measure $\mu_f$", however, in other materials, the term "spectral measure" is used. I noticed that the Borel measure is a spectral measure if there exists an orthogonal basis formed by spectrum of $A$, but then I also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#:%7E:text=a%20real%20eigenvalue.-,Spectral%20theorem,consisting%20of%20eigenvectors%20of%20T.) that the compact self-adjoint operator $A$ can have such result. So, can someone explain me more about the details here why P.Walters theorem is different from others?

Comment: Usually the infinitesimal generator is not compact (consult any of the usual examples, where it is not even bounded). A finite Borel measure and a spectral measure are two distinct things, which is evident from their definition. To a spectral measure $\mu$ and $\psi \in \mathcal{H}$ we can associate a finite Borel measure $\mu_f$ by $\mu_f(A) = \langle \psi, \mu (A) \psi \rangle$, where $A$ is some set in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the spectrum.

Comment: @jd27 Okay, so it seems like the idea here is that by normal Spectral Theorem, we have a unique spectral measure $\mu$, which implies we can create a unique borel measure $\mu_f$ with $\mu_f(A) = <\mu(A)\psi, \psi>$ . Is that what you mean?